# Getting Distinct results while joining tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables

**user_listings and user_listing_photos**

i want to join both of these tables but at the same time i want to get unique **url as per user_listing_id from user_listing_photos table.**

and in the results i want everything from the user_listings table and url from the user_listing_photos table.

```
        DB::table('user_listings')
        ->join('user_listing_photos', 'user_listings.id', 'user_listing_photos.user_listing_id')
        ->select('user_listings.*, user_listing_photos.url')
        ->where('user_listings.user_id', $page->user_id)
        ->where('publish_status', 1)
        ->select([DB::RAW('DISTINCT(user_listing_id)')])
        ->get();
```

[Here is the results that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppQSs.jpg)

so it seems like this part of the query is not running, its not getting everything from user_listings table plus no url from the user_listing_photos

```
->select('user_listings.*, user_listing_photos.url')
```

Comment: May I suggest creating relationships in the Models, which would provide much more ease getting related data from different tables: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Comment: Does the column name same in both tables, I mean url field?

Comment: @ByWaleed Thank you i was able to resolve the issue by using models relationship.

Comment: @Sam Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping your results by user_listing_id.

```
DB::table('user_listings')
        ->join('user_listing_photos', 'user_listings.id', 'user_listing_photos.user_listing_id')
        ->select('user_listings.*, user_listing_photos.url')
        ->where('user_listings.user_id', $page->user_id)
        ->where('publish_status', 1)
        ->groupBy('user_listing_id')
        ->select([DB::RAW('DISTINCT(user_listing_id)')])
        ->get();
```

Comment: same results, nothing changed at all.